# Accessing shared modules from child packages

Tags: python

I'm having difficulties with using internal imports inside my projects. This is a partial tree structure of my project:

```
app
  |- Gui.py
  |- Main.py
  |- logger.py
  |- config.py
  |- WebParser (package)
        |- __init__.py
        |- LinksGrabber.py
        |- LyricsGrabber.py
        |- ImagesGrabber.py
  |- (Many other packages...)
```

the `logger.py` and `config.py` modules are required in every package's modules, and are independent (uses only bulit-in modules). It is tricky to access these modules from inside packages.

This is how I tried to achieve it, for enabling configuration access and logging feature in `WebParser\LinksGrabber.py`:

```
# WebParser\__init__.py:
sys.path.append('..') # for outside-package modules
import config
from logger import log

# WebParser\LinksGrabber.py:
import WebParser
config = WebParser.config
log = WebParser.log
```

The Problems:

- This has code smell. I bet there is a better way to achieve this behaviour.
- I want to call `import WebParser` and use `WebParser.LinksGrabber` and `WebParser.LyricsGrabber` right away, without implicitly importing them. This can be done with importing the modules inside `__init__.py`, but it isn't possible because every package's module imports the package itself, and it will issue recursive imports.

Can you suggest a better implemention, or a different code design?

Comment: When you say "every module imports the package itself", which modules do you mean?  Do you mean that all the modules in the outer directory (config, Gui, etc.) import WebParser, but also all the modules inside WebParser import those outside modules?  Or do you just mean that the modules inside WebParser import WebParser itself?

Comment: I mean that every module inside WebParser imports WebParser itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `app` a package by giving it an `__init__.py` file.  The python relative import system only works *inside packages*.  Then inside your WebParser modules, you can do `from .. import config`, `from .. import Gui`, etc.

As for importing WebPackage from the packages inside it, that is a bit of a code smell.  Why do you need to do that?  Using relative imports you could instead, for instance, have `from . import LinksGrabber` inside ImagesGrabber, etc., to access what you need.  If there are functions that are part of the WebParser package that are needed by many of the submodules, you should pull those out into a separate module in WebParser.

Comment: Aren't `from . import LinksGrabber` and `import LinksGrabber` the same? And isn't `__init__` supposed to implement functions needed by many submodules? Perhaps I don't understand the purpose of the `__init__.py` file besides defining a specific folder as a package.

Comment: `__init__` is supposed to initialize the package.  Often it is simply an empty file.  Sometimes it imports particular submodules to give easier access to them as you are doing.  But it's not really the place for "package-wide" common functions.  Those should be in a separate module inside the package.  The reason is just what you found: if you try to use `__init__` to hold common functions *and* to import the submodules, but the submodules need the common functions, you have circular import problems.  Separate the initialization from the common functions.

Comment: Also `from . import LinksGrabber` and `import LinksGrabber` are the same in Python 2 if absolute imports are not enabled (i.e., if there is no `from __future__ import absolute_import`).  If absolute imports are enabled (as they always are in Python 3), then `import LinksGrabber` will not work.  Also, note that `from . import LinksGrabber` is not the same as `import WebParser`, which is what you seemed to say you were doing.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the entire outer (app) directory a python package (with an __ init__.py).

```
app_files
  |- ***setup.py***
  |- app
    |- ***__init__.py***
    |- Gui.py
    |- Main.py
    |- logger.py
    |- config.py
    |- WebParser (package)
          |- __init__.py
          |- LinksGrabber.py
          |- LyricsGrabber.py
          |- ImagesGrabber.py
    |- (Many other packages...)
```

setup.py would be something simple like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='app',
      version='1.0',
      description='My app',
      author='Greg Ward',
      packages=['app'],
     )
```

then you can run `python setup.py install`, to permanently install 'app' into the python path.
This is, in my opinion, the best way to do it without resorting to sys.path hacks everywhere.

Then, from anywhere in python you can refer to any of your files from the full dotted paths

i.e.

```
import app.logger
import app.config
import app.WebParser
```

The only way to make LinksGrabber and LyricsGrabber available from just an import app.WebParser would be to import them from app.WebParser.__ init__.

Comment: Note that the issue of whether `app` is a package is separate from whether it's installed systemwide using `setup.py`.  In many cases (for instance, when developing) you might not want to be using `setup.py` to install it all the time.  But if you give it an `__init__.py` and ensure that the package directory is on the system path, then it will work.

Comment: When developing I recommend you use 'python setup.py develop' to install into the system path with (what is essentially) a symbolic link to the directory you install from. That way as you make changes they are propagated to the system immediately.

What BrenBarn says is correct, that you don't need a setup.py to install onto the system path... but any other method will feel hackish.

Comment: I'm not sure if permantly appending the top-level folder into the `PYTHONPATH` is the right thing to do. The question is not about wheter to do it "permantly" or "temporary", but to find a little less-hacky way. Relative imports seems like a better idea. +1 fot the nice approach, though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you could use [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) here:

```
from .. import config
from ..logger import log
```

Comment: This will not work unless you make the outer `app` directory a package by giving it an `__init__.py`.

Comment: @BrenBarn -- Agreed.  I guess I just assumed that was a given, but maybe that's a bad assumption... and maybe adding `__init__.py` is the "better implementation" that the OP is asking about ;^).